# Convert OpenCV code to Emgu CV

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, emgucv

How to convert this C++ OpenCV code to C# Emgu CV code?

```
typedef Point3_<double> Point3d;
typedef DataType<double> Type1;
typedef Vec<double, 2> Type2;
typedef Mat_<double> Type3;
typedef Point_<double> Point2d;
```

Maybe it looks easy, but I could not find **Point3_** in Emgu CV.

Answer (score 1):

Find it under [Emgu.CV.Point3D](http://sourceforge.net/p/emgucv/svn/309/tree/trunk/Emgu.CV/PointAndLine/Point3D.cs) :)

Comment: Many thanks! And what about DataType? How I can find equivalent types and structures in Emgu?

Comment: I don't know what a `DataType` is. Where is it used? You can add a code sample to your question

Comment: Just the declaration doesn't help understand how/where it is being used. Nevertheless, I think that `DataType` is just the `TDepth` on your `Mat<...TDepth...>`